# Solo me saca un campo de la base de datos en el XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Estoy teniendo un error de sintaxis que no logro encontrar.
Estoy sacando un XML por pantalla sacando la información de la base de datos.

El código es el siguiente

```php
    public function renderXML(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Productos_1";
        $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
        if($result->rowCount() > 0){
            while($row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        $xml = new XMLWriter();
        $xml->openURI('php://output');
        $xml->setIndent(true);
        $xml->startDocument( '1.0" encoding="Windows-1252' );
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $xml->startElement('producto');
            $xml->writeAttribute('id',$value[$key]['id']);
            $xml->writeElement('nombre',$value[$key]['nombre']);
            $xml->writeElement('descripcion',$value[$key]['descripcion']);
            $xml->writeElement('imagen', $value[$key]['name_img']);
            $xml->endElement();
            $key++;
        }
        $xml->endElement();
        }
        header('Content-type: text/xml');
        $xml->flush();
        return $xml;
    }
```

y el resultado que muestra es el siguiente (1 solo dato de 300 que hay).

```xml
<producto id="1">
<nombre>Producto_133213</nombre>
<descripcion>Producto_133213</descripcion>
<imagen/>
</producto>
```

Espero que me ayuden. 
Gracias

Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer tu problema se encuentra en el recorrido de tu ciclo. 
En la asignación el foreach  te descompone recorriendo tu arreglo, ejemplo:

```
$a = array();
$a[0][0] = "a";
$a[0][1] = "b";
$a[1][0] = "y";
$a[1][1] = "z";

foreach ($a as $v1) { //le envía a $v1 {0,1} de la primera posición del arreglo $a
    foreach ($v1 as $v2) { //le envía a $v2 {0,1} de la segunda posición del arreglo $a
        echo "$v2\n"; //por lo que imprimiría "a,b,y,z"
    }
} //Si te fijas no hay necesidad de incrementar la variable para recorrer.
```

En tu caso creo tu solución sería la siguiente:

```
foreach ($data as $key) {
    foreach ($key => $value) {
        $xml->startElement('producto');
        $xml->writeAttribute('id',$value['id']);
        $xml->writeElement('nombre',$value['nombre']);
        $xml->writeElement('descripcion',$value['descripcion']);
        $xml->writeElement('imagen', $value['name_img']);
        $xml->endElement();
    }
}
```

Espero te ayude, aquí la **[documentación de PHP](https://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)**.

Saludos.